# Format %ld (%lx, %li, %lu and etc) doesn't work in Swift 4.2?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode10

Please help me. I updated to `Xcode 10` where is a `Swift 4.2`. And now format `%ld` (also others) doesn't work anymore. Who knows what should I use instead that?

```
let name = String(format: "Pic_%ld", value)
```

Part of code:

```
if value != 0 && value != 6 && value != 9 {
    let name = String(format: "Pic_%ld", value)
    print("Pic_%ld")
    print(value)
    let tileNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: name)
    print(name)
    tileNode.size = CGSize(width: Width, height: Height)
    var point = pointFor(column: column, row: row)
    point.x -= Width/2
    point.y -= Height/2
    tileNode.position = point
    tilesLayer.addChild(tileNode)
}
```

And see that

```
Pic_%ld
-4
2018-09-23 19:46:52.799361+0800 [20784:2265405] SKTexture: Error loading image resource: "Pic_-4"
Pic_-4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can format any string by following example .

```
string =  " \(aNumber) and \(aString)" // wher aNumber is a Int , aString is a string Variable
```

in you case it should be:

```
name = "Pic_\(value)"
```

Comment: I guess this is not an option for OP because afaik it doesn't allow to format output.

Answer (score 0):

So your code works fine.

```
// This command prints "Pic_%ld" because there is no formatting, it's just a string
print("Pic_%ld")

// This command prints "-4" because it's the value of the variable 
print(value)

// And these commands prints "Pic_-4". Because your value is -4 
let name = String(format: "Pic_%ld", value)
print(name)
```

And also you get this error

> SKTexture: Error loading image resource: "Pic_-4"

for an obvious reason, there is no such image in your resources. but anyway, `String` formatting works fine in your case.